# running script in Spyder(Python 2.7) does not show me output

Tags: python-2.7, spyder

I created directory as Python trial in C drive.
then I wrote some script:

```
import os
 os.chdir ("C:\python trial")
 obj= open("log.txt", "r")
 s= obj.read()
 print (s)
```

Before running , I went to Run->Configure-> Execute in a new dedicated Python Console->Ok
Now, when I run this on Spyder python 2.6

I am not able to see my output
On the right side side, In Console tab, I am able to see some lines like
show_elapsed_time= show_elapsed_time
and so on..

What wrong, I am doing here.
I am new to python and Spyder IDE

Thanks

Comment: When you run just `print ("text")` do you see anything?

Comment: @Psytho: No, I see the same kind of messages, which i mentioned earlier , I see under Console tab

Comment: What do you call "right side"? Variable explorer? If you new to Python and Spyder, it's better then you start with reading manuals.

Comment: @Psytho : Right side means Console tab.Thanks for the suggestion. I am going through it. But, what could be the problem like , I am not able to see my Output

Comment: the same code when I write on online editor, I am getting Output

Comment: You need to go to the tab called `IPython console`, not `Console`. Also, please post a screenshot of what you're seeing in Spyder to understand better your problem.

Comment: Please find attached screen shots

Comment: @ Carlos Cardoba :Here is the link:  https://imgur.com/Hk7ovWB